# binance-api - how to get close price and trade volume for last minute?

Tags: binance-api-client

I went through several binance APIs and all examples I saw seem pretty complex to what I need. I would like to get each minute close price and trade volume for last minute. I there an example that I could use please? By strean or HTTP GET? Thank you very much!